# SQL Query design involving multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am working on a MYSQL query design that, in my opinion, is pretty hard. I'm not experienced in SQL, so I found it really dificult. The point is:

I've got the 'ordertable' table which stores the order of some codes (AA, BB, CC..). In another table, 'AllTables' I store the name of a table associated to a code (AA -> tableA). Finally, 'tableA' table stores some data of diferent units (unit1, unit2...).

### **CASE 1.**

**ordertable** : Order of codes is given like:

```
+----------------+------+
| split_position | code |
+----------------+------+
|              1 | AA   |
|              2 | BB   |
|              3 | CC   |
|              4 | DD   |
+----------------+------+
```

### **CASE 2.**

**ordertable** Order of codes is given like:

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| id    | pos1 | pos2 | pos3 | pos4 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| unit1 | AA   | BB   | DD   | CC   | 
| unit2 | CC   | BB   | AA   | DD   | 
| unit3 | BB   | DD   | CC   | AA   |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

In **Case 2** we can also find special codes like 'var15':

```
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
| id    | pos1 | pos2  | pos3 | pos4  |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
| unit1 | AA   | var15 | DD   | var37 | 
| unit2 | CC   | BB    | AA   | DD    | 
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
```

In case we find something similar to 'var'+ number the associated table is always the same: 'variable', where de 'id' is the number of the code 'var37' -> id = 37.

**variable**

```
+-----+------------+------+--------+
| id  | name       | time | active |
+-----+------------+------+--------+
| 15  | Pedro      |    5 |      1 |
| 17  | Maria      |    4 |      1 |
+-----+------------+------+--------+
```

Info of tables:

**AllTables**

```
+------+------------+
| code | name       |
+------+------------+
| AA   | tableA     |
| BB   | tableB     |
| CC   | tableC     |
| DD   | tableD     |
+------+------------+
```

**tableA**

```
+-------+------+------+--------+
| id    | name | time | active |
+-------+------+------+--------+
| unit1 | Mark |   11 |      1 |
| unit2 | Jame |   20 |      0 |
+-------+------+------+--------+
```

**tableB**

```
+-------+------+------+--------+
| id    | name | time | active |
+-------+------+------+--------+
| unit1 | Mari |   44 |      1 |
| unit3 | nam2 |   57 |      1 |
+-------+------+------+--------+
```

Given an id='unit1', I'm expecting the next:

**Result**

```
+----------------+------+-------+-------+--------+
| split_position | code |  name | time  | active |
+----------------+------+-------+-------+--------+
|              1 | AA   | Mark  |  11   |    1   |
|              2 | BB   | Mari  |  44   |    1   |
|              3 | CC   |       |       |    0   |
|              4 | DD   |       |       |    0   |
+----------------+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

In case that the id (unit1) does not exists in tableC or tableD, 'split_position' and 'code' associated should appear but in the 'active' field should appear a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bit of a steep learning curve, but basically you have to declare a cursor and loop
over the each row in the ordertable and select your data then UNION the result together using dynamic SQL.

check this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68e333/4)

to order by final result by split position ASC just add `ORDER BY split_position ASC` to the sql variable before executing it like this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c9a6/1)

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! I'm impressed! It works really well. Is there any easy way to order the final result by split_position ASC? I'm not able to do it.

Comment: Thanks man! Just what I was searching for. Thanks again!
A last question (I promise). In case that 'ordertable' is given as Case 2 (check my updated question, please), would be easy to adapt the fantastic query you made to obtain the same result?

Comment: if your ordertable is like case 2 like you mentioned, you have to drastically change your stored procedure maybe something like this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8d82/4)

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't want to be a nuisance here, Tin Tran  but I have to slightly modify this awesome query you did and I feel a little disoriented without your help. As you can see, I updated CASE 2 in my question. Would you mind taking a look at this and say me if it is feasible or if it is really hard? Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help @tintran. I've implemented it and everything works perfect, I only have two questions. How could I rename the ouput column name? I tried the 'AS' but seems not to work. And how could I count the number of coincidences (rows)that appears in the answer? I promise I have tried myself to do it but I feel stuck

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bf66/1) like this sqlfiddle, I have renamed them all to COLUMN_1 and so on but remember the ORDER BY at the end too it's ordering by COLUMN_1

Comment: AWESOME!! Fou counting the number of results that appear I tried a count() but seems not to work. Perhaps we could put a counter in the loop in the function. What do you think?

Comment: because count(*) is an aggregate function i wouldn't know how to put it in there? can't you just do that from code and check how many rows are returned?

Comment: Yes, I think it will be the best solution. Thanks for all your help Tin Tran.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem you would need something like the following:

```
select split_position, code, name, time, active
from
(
select 'tableA' as tablename, id, [name], [time], active
from tableA
union all select 'tableB' as tablename, id, [name], [time], active
from tableB
) as tbls
inner join alltables atbls
on tbls.tablename=atbls.name
inner join ordertable ot
on atbls.code=ot.code
where tbls.id='unit1'
```